# Update masivo en mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Tengo un problema con la actualización de una base de datos ya que tengo que actualizar casi 1.700.000 de registros de usuarios  y quizás insertar nuevos registros pero no sé cómo realizar una consulta para hacerlo masivamente, además de esos casi 2 millónes de registros está relacionada con otra tabla que clasifica a cada usuario la relación entre esas dos tablas se hace mediante el ID del usuario y el ID de la clasificación, el problema consiste en que para actualizar los usuario me toca mediante el número de documento y no por el ID.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Esto es mysql o sql-server? porque pusiste las dos etiquetas.. y cual seria sobre todo el problema que estas teniendo? porque como planteaste la pregunta, no hay mucha ayuda para darte... que problema tuviste?

Comment: Para preguntas de esta naturaleza, sugiero que agregues la estructura base de las tablas (no hace falta todos los campos) y sus relaciones, así como un pequeño conjunto de datos de ejemplo, para que se logre entender lo que quieres lograr. Un saludo.